# Use custom field value as href

Tags: custom-field, footer

I created a custom field and would like to use its value as the href on a  tag that would go on my footer.

The custom field is on the Settings > General area of the dashboard and I used add_settings_field() in order to create it.

So, for example, the value inserted in my custom field is "https://www.google.com" and I would like that in my href. It would basically look like this:

```
<a href="CUSTOM FIELD VALUE GOES HERE">Click Here</a>
```

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To retrieve a value after using [add_settings_field()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) you should use [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).

So you could do something like this...

```
$value = esc_html(get_option('option_name'));

if ($value) {
    echo '<a href="' . $value . '">Click Here</a>';
}
```

You just need to change `option_name` to your field name.  The code will grab the value and if it isn't false echo the link.  Also added the escaping.

*Updated after OP gave more details

Comment: It would be nice to do some escaping in there... Otherwise you're creating vulnerability...

Comment: my custom field is on the settings > general are though..

Comment: You should include all relevant info when you ask a question. How did you create the field?  My guess is add_settings_field() is being used and in that case you could use $value = get_option( 'my_field').  Let me know if this is correct, update your question and I will update the answer

Comment: my bad! that worked though ;) i'll edit the question. thank you very much!